# Why a-d behaves differently in context index in oracle

Tags: indexing, oracle10g, oracle-text, ora-29855

I am using oracle 10g and i think i have `contains` clause issue.

This is below query. I have three environment dev,val and prod.

```
SELECT ABBRT.ID ,ABBRT.ABBREVIATION ,ABBRT.STATUSCODE ,ABBRT.FULLFORM ,APPLT.LABEL ,ABBRT.REMARK ,ABBRT.STATECODE
FROM ABBREVIATION ABBRT,APPLICABILITY APPLT,ABBREVIATION_APPLICABILITY AAT
WHERE 1=1
AND ABBRT.ID=AAT.ABBREVIATIONID
AND AAT.APPLICABILITYID=APPLT.ID
AND upper(ABBRT.STATECODE)='V'
AND ((contains(ABBRT.ABBREVIATION,'a\-d') > 0) OR (contains(ABBRT.FULLFORM,'a\-d') > 0))
ORDER BY ABBRT.ID
```

When i run this query on dev is working fine i am getting expected result but when i run this query on val and prod i am not getting expected result.

**For Information:**

```
a\-d: when i search this data i am not getting result.
a\-in:  when i search this data i am not getting result.
a\-e:  when i search this data i am getting result.
a\-f:  when i search this data i am getting result.
```

The above behaviour happens on all dev, val and prod environment.

I don't know whether is problem. I want to ask why it is problem only `a\-d` and `a\-in` only.
Why not others. But this is working on dev why.

Same value is there on val,dev and prod.

`ABBREVIATION` and `FULLFORM` column is `clob` type.
It has context index they have used on both `ABBREVIATION` and `FULLFORM` column.
When i checked that on sql this index query generated by sql on dev

```
 CREATE INDEX "F280"."IDX_ABBR_ABBR" ON "F280"."ABBREVIATION" ("ABBREVIATION") 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" PARAMETERS ('replace stoplist empty_stoplist');
```

`PARAMETERS` attribute has this value   `replace stoplist empty_stoplist`.

When i checked that on val and prod on val is null and on prod PARAMETERS   SYNC (on commit).

I have tried to re creation of index by droping and again creation. still i am fail

I also tried this query on val to synch as it is on dev but i am getting error.

**Query:**

```
 CREATE INDEX "F280"."IDX_ABBR_ABBR" ON "F280"."ABBREVIATION" ("ABBREVIATION") 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" PARAMETERS ('replace stoplist empty_stoplist');
```

**Error:**

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11000: invalid keyword REPLACE
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 364
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

I have tried this index also on val but it is being created but not reflecting

```
CREATE INDEX "F280"."IDX_ABBR_FULLFORM" ON "F280"."ABBREVIATION"
  (
    "FULLFORM"
  )
  INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" PARAMETERS
  (
    'SYNC(on commit)'
  );
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to shrink the query - it contains too much clauses which do not seem relevant for the issue. Means, is the issue also reproduceable with a query like `SELECT ABBRT.ABBREVIATION FROM ABBREVIATION ABBRT WHERE contains(ABBRT.ABBREVIATION,'a\-d') > 0);` and `SELECT ABBRT.ABBREVIATION FROM ABBREVIATION ABBRT WHERE contains(ABBRT.ABBREVIATION,'a\-e') > 0);`? Do you also get different results for those in one environment, but not in the other?